# Finding items with selenium driver when coming from an API call and they are not in the DOM

Tags: python, selenium

I work with complex apps made in Angular. I usually need to select items in dropdowns that are not in the DOM as the list of items comes from an API call and they are only displayed in the DOM in span tags after they are selected. Only after selecting some items they are displayed in span tags in the DOM but before they are selected, they never show up. Sometimes it works something like this code below that I got from SELENIUM IDE but usually both, the IDE and the driver, fail as they cannot find these items.

```
# 1) This click does the API call and opens the dropdown displaying the list of items that become available to select 
# driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#dropdown-5 .bxb-dropdown-value-n").click()
# 2) Sometimes it works something like this (code found by Selenium IDE) but this class #dropdown-item-6879 never shows in the DOM, even when you can see the item selected with the text in it
# driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#dropdown-item-6879 .value").click()
```

I usually get the exception: "ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"

But even when the IDE generates this code it ususally fails. I'd appreciate some help if possible. Many thanks!

Comment: "they are only displayed in the DOM in span tags after they are selected."  How can you (or a user) select them if they don't show in the DOM?  Are they drawn in a canvas?  It sounds like what you need is a webdriverwait.  That's needed when JS updates the DOM.

Comment: Share the URL of webpage if its public site else you can show relevant html of the page. to reporduce your problem also go through [tour] and [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. There are not much details to understand your problem

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share the link, it is not public. I could print the list of items iterating from an element above. Hopefully I will access to them some way, it is tricky as they are not seem in the DOM, the timers dont work, I tried, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In case it is useful for anyone: finally I could print the list of items iterating from a father element so I knew that even when the list of items is not showed in the inspector, there are span tags for all items:

```
subtypesList = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/span[@class = "value-content"]' ) 
for e in subtypesList:
    print(e.text)
```

Then, I can grab each item in the list by tag and text and once I have select it, I see it in the inspector/DOM:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#dropdown-0 .bxb-dropdown-placeholder").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), '3PL')]").click()
```